# Why can't I access protected variable in subclass?

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class, protected

I have an abstract class with a protected variable

```
abstract class Beverage
{
        protected string description;

}
```

I can't access it from a subclass. Intellisense doesn't show it accessible. Why is that so?

```
class Espresso:Beverage
{
    //this.description ??
}
```

Comment: and what is the error message? could you please post the line which fails? as it is now commented out, it won't compile just because it's not inside any method.

Comment: There is no error message. It's just not accessible inside class. As answers suggest it's accessible inside methods.

Comment: Well, actually, **nothing** is accessible outside methods. If would fail exactly the same way if it would be `public` instead of `protected`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: `description` is a special type of variable called a "[field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)". You may wish to read up on fields [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx).

Long answer: You must access the protected field in a constructor, method, property, etc. of the subclass.

```
class Subclass
{
    // These are field declarations. You can't say things like 'this.description = "foobar";' here.
    string foo;

    // Here is a method. You can access the protected field inside this method.
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        string bar = description;
    }
}
```

Inside a `class` declaration, you declare the *members* of the class. These may be fields, properties, methods, etc. These are not imperative statements to be executed. Unlike code inside a method, they simply tell the compiler what the members of the class are.

Inside certain class members, such as constructors, methods, and properties, is where you put your imperative code. Here is an example:

```
class Foo
{
    // Declaring fields. These just define the members of the class.
    string foo;
    int bar;

    // Declaring methods. The method declarations just define the members of the class, and the code inside them is only executed when the method is called.
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        // When you call DoSomething(), this code is executed.
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ufuk: See my edits to my original answer. You must understand the difference between class members code that is executed when a method is called--this is a very important concept in object-oriented programming!

Answer (score 2):

You can access it from within a method. Try this:

```
class Espresso : Beverage
{
    public void Test()
    {
        this.description = "sd";
    }
}
```

Comment: Abstract has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @Steven: and `protected`, too. :-)